# Reason behind Poincare's generalisation of the law of inertia

Tags: classical-mechanics

In Poincare's [Science & Hypothesis](https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/p/poincare/henri/science-and-hypothesis/chapter6.html) [Chapter 6], he starts with Galileo's famous

> ($1$) Principle of Inertia — A body acted on by no force can only move
>   uniformly in a straight line.

He then claims that the natural generalisation of  ($1$) is

> ($2$) The acceleration of a body depends only upon the position of this body
>   and of the neighboring bodies and upon their velocities.

Said mathematically, the motion of bodies depend on second order differential equations.

To motivate this generalisation, he gives a few alternatives, I'll include one of them here. Suppose instead that the position of a body doesn't change if it's acted by no force. Then the velocity of a body depends on its position and its neighbouring bodies. Mathematically, the differential equation of motion would be first order.

But I still can't see why ($2$) is a generalisation of ($1$).

Comment: Unfortunately for you, Poincare, while he knows what he is talking about, has a slightly flowery language that gives rise to fairly trivial problems of interpretation. If you read "depends only" as a general function, then the statement is simply 100% wrong. It takes quite a bit of specialization to exclude things like constant terms and n-body forces, all of which are a no-no to nature but arise from Poincare's choice of language. Generally, I would put it this way: he was a brilliant mathematician and an absolutely lousy physics teacher. Stick to Galileo and Newton.